# How to emit event in socketio inside a loop in python?

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I have an app which convert audio file to text using google speech to text api, then upload the file to the aws s3 and finally save the link and recognized text to database.

I need to process 1 hundred audio files so I need to loop it and emit event to the client about the current progress. But the problem is whenever I emit event to the client, the client will not receive it until all the process is done and most of the time the socket will disconnect and will reconnect after all the process is done.

Im using:
Flask-socketio
python v3.8

This is entry point of the app:

```
from ats import socketio, app, db

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

This is the code snippet of the loop:

```
for file in audioFiles:

    # Convert file to text
    recognizedText = AUDIO.convert(file)

    # Upload file to aws s3
    bucket = app.config['BUCKET']
    location = app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']

    filePath = join(location, foldername, file)
    url = S3.upload_file(filePath, bucket)

    # Save the audiofile to database
    newAudio = {
        'productId': productId,
        'name': file,
        'link': url,
        'recognizedText': recognizedText,
    }
    Audio.add(newAudio)

    # emit event to update the client about the progress
    percent = math.floor((currentFile / float(fileCount) ) * 100)

    emit('upload_progress', {'data': percent}, room=sid, namespace='/') # This emit will not reach the client side until the loop is done.
    currentFile += 1
```

And most of the time the socket will disconnect before all process is done. Any suggestions or fix for this guys?
I would be very helpful as I am beginning to learn how to develop apis with Flask.

Comment: After few hours of searching for a solution, i get it working by just adding just a line of code.

emit('upload_progress', {'data': percent}, room=sid, namespace='/')
eventlet.sleep() # added this line
I don't exactly know the logic behind it but it works :D

But still the disconnection problem is still there, if the process will take few seconds the client will be disconnected from the server. How to solve this disconnection problem? Thanks

Comment: Have you done the eventlet monkey patching?

Comment: I haven't use tried it sir, I will try it later if it will work. And by the way what I did to avoid the socket from disconnecting is I put eventlet.sleep() under the these lines "recognizedText = AUDIO.convert(file)" and "url = S3.upload_file(filePath, bucket)". Its just a quick fix for now, but I will definitely try eventlet monkey patching. Thanks for the suggestion sir.